# Using the clearInterval the function when function meets some condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval, clearinterval

How can I use the clearInterval the function when function meets some condition?

Code:-

```
var checkRecordlock = function() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/project/crl/Mzk="
  }).done(function(data) {
    var is_locked = data.locked;
    if (is_locked == 1) {
      alert("Locked");
    }
  });
}

checkRecordlock();
var checkRecordlockIntervalId = setInterval(checkRecordlock, 100);
```

I want to clear the interval of the function if `is_locked == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
checkRecordlock();
var checkRecordlockIntervalId = setInterval(checkRecordlock, 100);

function checkRecordlock() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/project/crl/Mzk="
  }).done(function(data) {
    var is_locked = data.locked;
    if (is_locked == 1) {
      clearInterval(checkRecordlockIntervalId);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: checkRecordlockIntervalId is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `checkRecordlock` before the interval. In order to stop it when the condition reaches, use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) and pass it `checkRecordlockIntervalId`. Here is an example:

```js
var checkRecordlock = function() {
    is_locked++;
    console.log(is_locked);
    if (is_locked == 10) {
      alert("Locked");
      clearInterval(checkRecordlockIntervalId)
    }
}
let is_locked = 0;
//checkRecordlock();
var checkRecordlockIntervalId = setInterval(checkRecordlock, 100);
```

Comment: But my is_locked is defined by another page using ajax. So I am not able to change is_locked value in ajax page after it if condition is true.

Comment: This is just an example. Are you facing any errors?

Comment: Yes, it's still running when I use ajax.